# How to find text in file not in workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to find text in file which is opened in Eclipse.
But that file is not included in workspace.
I am using Juno version.

Comment: grep is effective if you don't mind stepping out of eclipse and into the command line. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: Oops! There is find command in edit menu not in search menu. Thanks.

Comment: Answer that comes to my mind is ctrl + f . But I'm sure you are expecting more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> does work :)

(<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> for Mac users)

And as mentioned this dialog can be opened via the menu: `Edit -> Find`